# How to get the name of a document in a collection after querying in Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, querying

I am programming an app in Flutter and I want to be able to query a set of documents in a collection in Firestore based on specific criteria and then with the documents that fit said criteria get the name of those documents. This is what I have tried so far however it does not work.

```
 getDoc(String topic, int grade) {
  return Firestore.instance
    .collection('active')
    .where(topic, isEqualTo: true)
    .where('grade', isEqualTo: grade)
    .getDocuments()
    .then((docRef) {
      return docRef.id;
    });
  }
```

All of the code works except for the part where I call docRef.id. When I call docRef.id I get an error saying:

```
The getter 'id' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'.
Try importing the library that defines 'id', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'id'.d
```

Comment: `docRef` is not actually a DocumentReference.  The error message is telling you that it's a QuerySnapshot.  You have to iterate the document snapshots in it to find out about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a query, the result you get in your `then` callback is a `QuerySnapshot`. Even if there's only one document matching the conditions, you'll get a `QuerySnapshot` with a single document in there. To get the individual `DocumentSnapshot` that are the result, you'll want to loop over the `QuerySnapshot.documents`.

Something like:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('active')
    .where(topic, isEqualTo: true)
    .where('grade', isEqualTo: grade)
    .getDocuments()
    .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.documens.forEach((doc) {
        print(doc.documentID)
      })
    });
```